# I am not able to access id from itemView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am learning to create RecyclerView using Kotlin from this video.

[RECYCLERVIEW - Android Fundamentals](https://youtu.be/HtwDXRWjMcU?t=1040)

According to this video I can access `tvTitle` and `cbDone` from `itemView`.

But in my code it is not showing any suggestion, and if I type by my self it show error.   [Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByGNT.jpg)

Comment: The video is outdated. It uses synthetics, which is deprecated now. The top comment under that video tells how to work around that

Comment: in the video author added like holder.itemView.apply{.... }

Comment: Just go with latest tutorials you need to initialize your xml widget in inner class to access that views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add,

plugins {
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

to build.gradle(:app).